# Updating jQuery UI sortable dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dynamic, jquery-ui-sortable, items

I'm using [jQuery UI `sortable`](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) on an unordered list. I want every list item to be sortable *except* for the one that has an `.active` class:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">Item 1</li> <!-- This item should NOT be sortable -->
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

So I've initialized the `sortable` like this:

```
$("ul").sortable({
    items: "li:not('.active')"
});
```

The problem is that clicking a list item moves the `.active` class to that item. For example, if I click the third item, I get:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="active">Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

But the `sortable` doesn't seem to "notice" that change, so the third item remains sortable.

How do I make the `items` option apply even when the `.active` class is added to a different item, so that the `sortable` handles it how I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dynamically check for this in the [start event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start).

If the target element has the `active` class, [cancel the action](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel) :

```
$('#list').sortable({
    items: 'li',
    start: function(e, ui){
        if ( ui.item.hasClass('active') ) {
        // "return false" does not work - the widget does not seem to consider
        //  that it should cancel the whole dragging, and enters a broken state.
        //
        // When this callback is executed, the "start" event is not
        // fully handled yet.
        // You have to wait for its end, then cancel the action :
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#list').sortable('cancel');
            }, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fnUz8/3/) - jQuery 1.8.3, jQuery-ui 1.9.2

Comment: Clever! Worked perfectly. Thanks!